# Obtener el path relativo desde un path absoluto en laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy utilizando [una librería de imágenes de spatie](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v10/introduction) en la que puedo obtener el path de la imagen, pero la obtengo completa, por ejemplo:
utilizando `$this->user->getFirstMedia('avatars')->getPath('thumb');` obtengo el path absoluto:

```
C:\laragon\www\new-tabimuse\storage\app/public\3663/conversions/rio-de-janeiro-thumb.jpg
```

y yo solamente quiero obtener:

```
3663/conversions/rio-de-janeiro-thumb.jpg
```

quisiera saber si existe alguna manera en laravel (en lo posible sin utilizar manipulación de strings) de obtener el path relativo desde un path absoluto, gracias :)

Comment: Te dejo un [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637945/getting-relative-path-from-absolute-path-in-php) a SO donde hay varias respuestas a este tema por si te sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que buscas el la función

```
$this->user->getFirstMedia('avatars')->getUrl();
```

De la doc de [Spatie Media Library](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v10/basic-usage/retrieving-media)

Comment: la función getUrl me obtiene la url absoluta también, yo solamente quiero el path relativo y actualmente para obtenerlo estoy utilizando manipulación de strings, que no es la mejor manera